# Email value is null. How to fix this?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase, forgot-password

I have made an forgot password page and it doesn't work. it says that my email is null. How can i fix this error? The login/register page does work but don't get an verification email.

This is the code from the forget_password page

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hetmaantje/reusable_widget.dart';
import 'package:hetmaantje/utils1/colors.dart';

class ResetPassword extends StatefulWidget {
  const ResetPassword({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ResetPasswordState createState() => _ResetPasswordState();
}

class _ResetPasswordState extends State<ResetPassword> {
  TextEditingController _emailTextController = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
        title: const Text(
          "Wachtwoord resetten",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
                hexStringToColor("FFBEC8"),
                hexStringToColor("fe98a8"),
                hexStringToColor("FC98A7"),
                hexStringToColor("#FF8799")
              ], begin: Alignment.topCenter, end: Alignment.bottomCenter)),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 120, 20, 0),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    reusableTextField("Vul je email in", Icons.person_outline, false,
                        _emailTextController),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    firebaseUIButton(context, "Reset je wachtwoord", () {
                      FirebaseAuth.instance
                          .sendPasswordResetEmail(email: _emailTextController.text)
                          .then((value) => Navigator.of(context).pop());
                    })
                  ],
                ),
              ))),
    );
  }
}
```

i think this part of the code is wrong but i don't know how to fix this. can anyone help me with this pleas.

```
    const SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    firebaseUIButton(context, "Reset je wachtwoord", () {
                      FirebaseAuth.instance
                          .sendPasswordResetEmail(email: _emailTextController.text)
                          .then((value) => Navigator.of(context).pop());
                    })
```

this is the reusableTextField:

```
    TextEditingController controller) {
  return TextField(
    controller: controller,
    obscureText: isPasswordType,
    enableSuggestions: !isPasswordType,
    autocorrect: !isPasswordType,
    cursorColor: Colors.white,
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.9)),
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      prefixIcon: Icon(
        icon,
        color: Colors.white70,
      ),
      labelText: text,
      labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.9)),
      filled: true,
      floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
      fillColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.3),
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
          borderSide: const BorderSide(width: 0, style: BorderStyle.none)),
    ),
    keyboardType: isPasswordType
        ? TextInputType.visiblePassword
        : TextInputType.emailAddress,
  );
}
```

This is the firebaseUIButton

```
Container firebaseUIButton(BuildContext context, String title, Function onTap) {
  return Container(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    height: 50,
    margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 20),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(90)),
    child: ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        onTap();
      },
      child: Text(
        title,
        style: const TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16),
      ),
      style: ButtonStyle(
          backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) {
            if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) {

              return Colors.pinkAccent.shade100;

            }
            return  hexStringToColor("FFBEC8");
          }),
          shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
              RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)))),
    ),

  );

}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. You can only pass a valid email through to that funciton, otherwise it'll fail. Without seeing what reusableTextField widget is or the firebaseUIButton, I can't help any further though.

Comment: i am sorry i have changed the question

Comment: You need to show where you define your function "firebaseUIButton". In the code you've shown, it's not defined anywhere.

Comment: i have the firebaseUiButton now defined in the question

Comment: how can i fix this?